# How to debug a JSON error (occuring in Wordpress Backend)?

Tags: java, json, wordpress, debugging

I am experiencing a problem with Wordpress.

Everything seems to work fine, but with the usage of some (3rd-party)-Blocks in the Gutenberg-editor, something is causing an issue, I assume with Java.

If the content in Wordpress is saved, an error occurs:

*Updating failed. The response is not a valid JSON response.*

There is not more to the error. Debug enabeling in wp-config does not log any errors. If I am right, this is correct, because this debug-function in WP would only log php related issues.

On the Internet there are all kinds of random solutions to fix this error (change permalinks as an example). Does not do anything for me. More random solutions are deactivating all plugins. Still, the issue persists. Update Wordpress and php. Done. Error persists.

All the above seems to be "searching in the dark". So I would like to know, how to find out, what the acutal issue is. Surely, there must be some kind of debugging?

I found something somewhere on the net in regards to get the last JSON-error from the server:

```
    if (!function_exists('json_last_error_msg')) {

        function json_last_error_msg() {

            static $ERRORS = array(

                JSON_ERROR_NONE => 'No error',

                JSON_ERROR_DEPTH => 'Maximum stack depth exceeded',

                JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH => 'State mismatch (invalid or malformed JSON)',

                JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR => 'Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded',

                JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX => 'Syntax error',

                JSON_ERROR_UTF8 => 'Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded'

            );



            $error = json_last_error();

            return isset($ERRORS[$error]) ? $ERRORS[$error] : 'Unknown error';

        }

    }

?>
```

If I understood this right, the above code should go in a .php-file, which I call trough the browser. Did it, tried it. Browser window remains just blank. So either this is not working for me, or there is just no error stored?

Who can point me in the right direction?

I also did create two test pages in WP, and tried to save both. One without the error causing element, and one with. Both attempts have been logged, using the Borwser's Developer-Tools on the "network" tab. If anybody thinks, this would be of help to evaluate the issue, let me know and I will upload them.